# Is docker swarm suitable for scheduling batch jobs/small jobs?

Tags: docker, scheduler, docker-swarm

Is there any use case where docker is used for batch jobs/small jobs, and that requires a scheduler queue to schedule them? In swarm, if we don't have enough resources, it rejects the request, and doesn't queue them. If we want to schedule batch jobs and services together, we will need a scheduler queue then. Is there any support for such use cases in swarm? I'm new to docker swarm. Please help :)

Comment: You might want to add a specific usercase to your question, e.g. "I have only 3 servers and each is doing batch job A and B".  Otherwise your question may be closed for being opinion based.

Comment: Which version of swarm?

Comment: @grochmal   i have 2 machines A and B each having 2gb of memory. i have to submit 4 jobs each with 2gb of memory and approx runtime of 10 seconds. Only 2 of them will get scheduled and the other 2 requests will be rejected, and as there is no scheduler queue at docker manager those jobs will never get scheduled.

Comment: Can you add that information in the question?  i.e. by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38980015/edit).  I need to admit that I never used docker-swarm, but I believe that if you make a well structured question you will get a good answer (and, in making a good question, I can help).

Comment: Far as I know there is no batch scheduling functionality in Swarm (yet). It might be worth your while looking into chronos (https://mesos.github.io/chronos/) a batch scheduler for Mesos. Mesos is an alternative to Swarm for managing a cluster of container engines.

Comment: There's a feature request in Docker Swarm to do batch scheduling: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23880

Comment: Kubernetes has this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/jobs/run-to-completion-finite-workloads/